# Google Drive iOS native application URL schemes

Tags: google-drive-api

I found that native iOS app for google drive which can be downloaded from AppStore supports URL scheme:

```
googledrive://
```

- Is there any documentation to this scheme or something where can I find how to authorize my application using google drive native iOS application?
- Is it even possible to authorize application this way?
- Is there other way to authorize then via web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to integrate Google Drive into your iOS application you should use [Google API's Objective-C client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) which has Google Drive support.

For authorization specifically the client library will use a Web view to initiate an OAuth 2 flow.

You can have a look at the [sample application](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/DriveSample) that uses Google Drive.

As for the iOS native Drive application there is currently no way to interact with it. Though if we do we are likely to add these features to the Objective-C client library anyways :)