# How to open one drive or google drive file link in native one drive or google drive app from our app in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to **One Drive** or **Google Drive** file link to open in native **One Drive** or **Google Drive** app.

Is it possible using `URLSchemes`?

Comment: There is a googledrive:// URL scheme according to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074977/google-drive-ios-native-application-url-schemes

Comment: it's possible to prepend googlesheets:// or googledocs:// to a normal sheet or document URL according to this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/227149 maybe this also works for googledrive://